# Android sdk setText error

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to figure out way this code isn't working.

The last line is giving me an warning

> "Do not concentrate text displayed with set text".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    double costPerAthlete=725.00;
    int numberOfAthletes;
    double totalCost;
    String locationChoice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
        final EditText tickets = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTickets);
        final Spinner location = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.txtLocation);
        Button cost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCost);
        cost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            final TextView result = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult));

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                numberOfAthletes = Integer.parseInt(tickets.getText( ).toString( ));
                totalCost = costPerAthlete * numberOfAthletes;
                DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.###");
                locationChoice = location.getSelectedItem( ).toString( );
                result.setText("Cost for" + locationChoice + "is" + currency.format(totalCost));

            }
        });
    }

}
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.matt.triathlon.RegistrationActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_registration">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txtTitle"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="32sp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:hint="@string/txtTickets"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtLocation"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    android:entries="@array/txtLocation"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:prompt="@string/prompt" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/triathalon"
    android:src="@drawable/triathalon"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnCost"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/triathalon"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/txtResult"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

These are my logs

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: 
main Process: com.matt.triathlon, PID: 2188 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.matt.triathlon/com.matt.triathlon.RegistrationActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
```

Comment: try see the value for locaitonChoice and currency.format(totalCost) before you setText

Comment: Been a while since I've worked with java, but System.println(locationChoice); System.println( currency.format(totalCost));  see what happens if you do that before you setText. I say this as I would console.log() if i were using javascript, so I'm not 100% that is the correct way, but may be worth checking out

Comment: the println is coming up red saying it can't resolve the method

Comment: which method is that ? I put System.println() i meant System.out.println(myObject);

Comment: Nah that didn't work.

Comment: it wants me to change the "+" symbols

Comment: It is a warning, not an error. You can safely ignore it

Comment: ok, so what do i have to do to get this to work?

Comment: every time i try to use the app in the emulator it crashes

Comment: Then post the logcat here

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.matt.triathlon, PID: 2188
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.matt.triathlon/com.matt.triathlon.RegistrationActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Activity

Comment: `findViewById` will return `null` if the ID that you gave it cannot be found in the contentView set by `activity_registration.xml`. Please check if you have a Button with the ID of `btnCost` in that file.

Comment: I do have the button btnCost

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35606870/2308683) to include the XML layout file?

Comment: did'nt you get a compilation error for the code you paster?? because you dont have any id as btnCost. thats a string type resource. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ID for the button in the layout is `android:id="@+id/button"`, not `android:id="@+id/btnCost"`.

That is why you are getting a NullPointerException.

Please either change the XML to use the correct ID, or change the Java code to

```
Button cost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Comment: that worked guys thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Button cost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCost);
```

to

```
Button cost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

It's always better to make youre own xmls and follow a convention for ids
I use tvName for (tv_name), btnLogin for (btn_login) etc so that i dont get confused.